# How to portably parse the (Unicode) degree symbol with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, portability

I'm writing a simple regular expression parser for the output of the `sensors` utility on Ubuntu. Here's an example of a line of text I'm parsing:

```
temp1:        +31.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

And here's the regex I'm using to match that (in Python):

```
temp_re = re.compile(r'(temp1:)\s+(\+|-)(\d+\.\d+)\W\WC\s+' 
                     r'\(crit\s+=\s+(\+|-)(\d+\.\d+)\W\WC\).*')
```

This code works as expected and matches the example text I've given above. The only bits I'm really interested in are the numbers, so this bit:

```
(\+|-)(\d+\.\d+)\W\WC
```

which starts by matching the `+` or `-` sign and ends by matching the `°C`.

My question is, why does it take two `\W` (non-alphanumeric) characters to match `°` rather than one? Will the code break on systems where Unicode is represented differently to mine? If so, how can I make it portable?

Comment: With the `re.UNICODE` flag that RE doesn't match with either `\W\WC` or `\WC`. Or, have I misunderstood you?

Comment: There's also “`℃`”, which is a _single_ character that means degrees celsius. Thanks a bunch, Unicode Consortium!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible portable solution:

Convert input data to unicode, and use `re.UNICODE` flag in regular expressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


data = u'temp1:        +31.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)'
temp_re = re.compile(ur'(temp1:)\s+(\+|-)(\d+\.\d+)°C\s+' 
                     ur'\(crit\s+=\s+(\+|-)(\d+\.\d+)°C\).*', flags=re.UNICODE)

print temp_re.findall(data)
```

Output

```
[(u'temp1:', u'+', u'31.0', u'+', u'107.0')]
```

**EDIT**

[@netvope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250827/netvope) allready pointed this out in comments for question.

**Update**

Notes from [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) comments about input encoding:

> `check_output()` returns binary data that sometimes can be text (that should have a known character encoding in this case and you can convert it to Unicode). Anyway ord(u'°') == 176 so it can not be encoded using ASCII encoding.

So, to decode input data to `unicode`, basically* you should use encoding from system locale using `locale.getpreferredencoding()` e.g.:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(...).decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

With data encoded correctly:

> you'll get the same output without re.UNICODE in this case.

---

Why basically? Because on Russian Win7 with `cp1251` as `preferredencoding` if we have for example `script.py` which decodes it's output to `utf-8`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

print u'temp1: +31.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)'.encode('utf-8')
```

And wee need to parse it's output:

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 
                         'script.py']).decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

will produce wrong results: `'В°'` instead `°`.

So you need to know encoding of input data, in some cases.

Comment: Sure, but a full working example for this sort of thing is always a good idea. Handling Unicode properly is difficult for a lot of programmers even when full facilities are available :(

Comment: +1: for "convert input data to unicode". btw, you'll get the same output without `re.UNICODE` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had a play with it. In the "real" code the data actually comes from the output of a call to `subprocess.check_output` which returns its data as ASCII, not Unicode, so this doesn't quite work there. Perhaps a more sensible thing would be to move to Python3 where "everything" is Unicode? Hmm.

Comment: @snim2: `check_output()` returns *binary data* that sometimes can be *text* ([that should have a known character encoding in this case](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and you can convert it to Unicode). Anyway `ord(u'°') == 176` so it can not be encoded using [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoding. Python 3 can't help you because `check_output` can return data that has no meaning as a text e.g., binary image data (you can't convert it to Unicode; there is no associated character encoding).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, sorry you're quite right. I'm getting confused as calling `.split(\n)` on the output of `check_output` works just fine in Python2, so it's easy to forget that there's more going on.

Comment: @snim2, I have no access to Ubuntu machine with `sensors` at this moment, but probably you should decode output from `subprocess.check_output` using system locale. e.g.: assuming `data` is result of `check_output`, then `data = data.decode('utf-8')` before doing regexp search.

Comment: @reclosedev: You might mean `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. It is completely independent from source encoding used for the script.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone for the help. I've created a gist of the final result here: https://gist.github.com/1652633 -- still needs a bit of work but the parsing seems to be accurate :-)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, thanks for very useful notes, i'll add them to answer.